# SFML and PN noise (8-bit emulation)

Tags: sfml, noise, commodore

I have had the absurd idea to write a Commodore VIC-20 emulator, my first computer.

Everything has gone quite well until sound emulation time has come! The VIC-20 has 3 voices (square waveform) and a noise speaker. Searching the net I found that it is a PN generator (somewhere is called "white" noise).

I know that white noise is not frequency driven, but you put a specific frequency value into the noise register (`POKE 36877,X` command). The formula is:

freq = cpu_speed/(127 - x)

(more details on the VIC-20 Programmer's Guida, especially the MOS6560/6561 VIC-I chip)

where x is the 7-bit value of the noise register (bit 8 is noise on/off switch)

I have a 1024 pre-generated buffer of numbers (the pseudo-random sequence), the question is: how can I correlate the frequency (freq) to create a sample buffer to pass to the sound card (in this case to `sf::SoundBuffer` that accepts `sf::Int16` (aka `unsigned short`) values?

I guess most of you had a Commodore VIC-20 or C64 at home and played with the old `POKE` instruction... Can anyone of you help me in understanding this step?

**EDIT:**

Searching on the internet I found the C64 Programmer's Guida that shows the waveform graph of its noise generator. Can anyone recognize this kind of wave/perturbation etc...? The waveform seems to be periodic (with period of freq), but how tu generate such wave?

[image: C64 noise waveform]